# SPARQL Negation: All foaf:Agents which aren't foaf:Persons

Tags: rdf, sparql, foaf

I am trying to write a SPARQL query which should give me all `foaf:Agents` which aren't `foaf:Persons`.

I can't see a way to apply [this OPTIONAL/BOUND construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375589/sparql-query-select-everything-except-things-that-match) to this problem, because all the properties like `rdfs:subClassOf` and `rdf:type` are transitive and reflexive.

I tried this:

```
SELECT * WHERE { 
?x rdf:type foaf:Agent 
OPTIONAL { ?y rdf:type foaf:Person } 
FILTER ( !BOUND(?y) ) }
```

But rdf:type seems to be transitive, at least with JENA/ARQ/SDB.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is because you have two separate variable bindings (`?x` and `?y`) which are unrelated in your query. So `?x` must be bound to appear in the result set (which is what you want), but if `?y` is unbound, you have not learned anything new about `?x`.

Update: In an ideal query, there would be no need for `?y` at all; you could test the incoming/outgoing edegs of `?x` directly. This is difficult (impossible?) to do in SPARQL 1.0 when you want to check if an edge does not exist on a given variable binding. However, [SPARQL 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#negation) will provide support for negation:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 

SELECT ?agent
WHERE 
{
    ?agent rdf:type foaf:Agent .
    FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?agent rdf:type foaf:Person . }
}
```

@Kingsley Idehen's approach (using third-party SPARQL extensions) should help you solve the problem in the short run.

Comment: But how do I set up a relation between ?x and ?y ?

Comment: SPARQL 1.1 is definitely going to have negation, the working group panel at ISWC 2009 were clear on that

Comment: Note that SPARQL 1.1 syntax (as specified in the link) is actually `FILTER NOT EXISTS` now (needs the `FILTER` keyword up front)

Answer (score 9):

To do this in SPARQL 1.0, you'd have to write:

```
SELECT * WHERE { 
     ?x rdf:type foaf:Agent 
     OPTIONAL { ?y rdf:type foaf:Person . FILTER (?x = ?y) . } 
     FILTER ( !BOUND(?y) ) 
}
```

[As Phil M says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1615946/2846923), SPARQL 1.1 will introduce new syntax to make this much more straightforward to write.

Answer (score 2):

> Via Virtuoso SPARQL Extensions
>   endpoint for verification
>   http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql (LOD Cloud Cache Instance)

```
SELECT distinct ?x ?o 
WHERE { 
?x a foaf:Agent .
?x ?p ?o.
filter (!bif:exists ((select (1) where { ?x a foaf:Person } ))) 
} 
limit 10
```

```
DESCRIBE ?x 
WHERE { 
?x a foaf:Agent .
filter (!bif:exists ((select (1) where { ?x a foaf:Person } ))) 
} 
limit 200
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the (draft) SPARQL 1.1 spec for negation: http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#negation

Answer (score 2):

The following now works, courtesy of SPARQL 1.1:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(?agent)
WHERE 
{
    ?agent rdf:type foaf:Agent .
    FILTER (NOT EXISTS { ?agent rdf:type foaf:Person . })
}
```

Live example links:

1. [Query Solution](http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX+rdf:+%3Chttp://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E+%0D%0APREFIX+foaf:+%3Chttp://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/%3E+%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+DISTINCT+COUNT(%3Fagent)%0D%0AWHERE+%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++++%3Fagent+rdf:type+foaf:Agent+.%0D%0A++++FILTER+(NOT+EXISTS+%7B+%3Fagent+rdf:type+foaf:Person+.+%7D)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)
2. [Query Definition](http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=PREFIX+rdf:+%3Chttp://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E+%0D%0APREFIX+foaf:+%3Chttp://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/%3E+%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+DISTINCT+COUNT(%3Fagent)%0D%0AWHERE+%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++++%3Fagent+rdf:type+foaf:Agent+.%0D%0A++++FILTER+(NOT+EXISTS+%7B+%3Fagent+rdf:type+foaf:Person+.+%7D)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)